# QGIS attribute form editor crashes on Spatialite source

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, spatialite

I have collected an attribute table (no geometry) together with other stuff in a Spatialite DB for easy portability. The idea was to hand off just one file and DB for field work.

The Problem: The attribute form created uses values from the attribute table inside the Spatialite DB to determine options for the form. This is handy, because the attributes and option for the form can be added to the table easily (new rows). However, QGIS crashes every time I open the info window on a map. If I use a .csv file instead it works properly. But I loose the dynamic, consolidated properties of the workflow...

As there are really no other File DB options, I am left with .csv, which I would rather avoid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share data to reproduce the issue? Have you opened a ticket?